# Catasto terreni ITALY

Tags: data-request, data.gov

I need to obtain catasto information for all the Italy limited to terreni only, no urban zone.

Is it possible to obtain this information free?

Anybody know any services for WFS or SHP download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but it's just a fee except for local governments that can trigger a convention

Comment: can you clarify that?